# How to inject secrets from vault to Kubernetes pods

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

All,

I have all my secrets stored in vault. How can I fetch secrets from vault and inject them in pods.

Do I have to use a sidecard for it or there is some easiest way also .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one great project on Github `Vault-CRD` in java: https://github.com/DaspawnW/vault-crd

Vault CRD for sharing Vault Secrets with Kubernetes. It injects & sync values from Vault to Kubernetes secret. You can use these secrets as environment variables inside pod.

Comment: Can you explain me how it can be used ?

Comment: it's so easy to configure you can follow these steps : https://vault.koudingspawn.de/how-does-vault-crd-work

Answer (score 2):

> **The sidecar pattern is common with Kubernetes applications and can be applied to access secrets from Vault**.

There is a great step by step walk through on [hands-on-with-vault-on-kubernetes](https://github.com/hashicorp/hands-on-with-vault-on-kubernetes) on git hub. This will answer all your basic questions on how to do this with example.

One more for your reference [Injecting Vault Secrets Into Kubernetes Pods via a Sidecar](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/injecting-vault-secrets-into-kubernetes-pods-via-a-sidecar/)